# How to "cross-product" types in typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I want to "cross-product" two types.

What I mean by 'cross-product of types' is, example I have 2 types,

```
type color = "red" | "green";
```

and

```js
type shade = "100" | "200" | "300";
```

I want to get a final type which accepts these string values only

```
"red.100"
"red.200"
"red.300"
"green.100"
"green.200"
"green.300"
```

I know I can do this...

```
type colorShade = "red.100" | "red.200" | "red.300" | "green.100" | "green.200" | "green.300";
```

... but as you can see, as either of the list grow, I would have to update the type `colorScheme` manually. How do I get the type `colorShade` without having to manually edit `colorScheme` directly?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a feature called `template literal types`:

```
type colorShade = `${color}.${shade}`
```

---

Docs: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html